# how to add Title, keyword and description different on every page of simple php website dynamically

Tags: php

How can I add a different title, keyword and description in every page's `<head>` of my simple php website dynamically?

E.g

```
<title>this is title</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2" />
<meta name="description" content="this is description" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create method to return title for current page, depending on where the user is, and then use it like this.

```
<title><?php echo get_title(); ?></title>
```

same with the keywords

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo get_keywords(); ?>" />
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo get_description(); ?>" />
```

The implementation will depend on how you navigate on the website. For example, if you have only `index.php`, and choose content by `$_GET["page"]`, you can have something like this

```
function get_title() {
   switch($_GET["page"]) {
      case "home":
         return "Welcome to my home page";
      case "guestbook":
         return "Welcome to guestbook";
   }
}
```

or you can make it all in one like

```
function get_headers() {
    // here set $title, $description and $keywords according to current page 
    // ....

    // then just generate html
    $html = "<title>$title</title>";
    $html .= "<meta name='description' content='$description' />";
    $html .= "<meta name='keywords' content='$keywords' />";

    return $html;
}
```

and then again do something like this

```
<head>
    ...
    <?php echo get_headers(); ?>
    ...
```

Comment: <title><?php echo get_title(); ?></title>
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo get_keywords(); ?>" />
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo get_description(); ?>" />
could some one make three of them in one function so it automatically select the title ,keyword,description